# How do I enable @click.middle?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to catch middle mouse button click event using `@click.middle`, but it seems that nothing happens. anyone know why? https://jsfiddle.net/c25e35uh/

```html
<div id="root">
  <button @click.middle="test()">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  methods: {
    test () {
        alert('me')
    }
  }
})
```

In their document, they said clearly that using `@click.middle` to catch event https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Mouse-Button-Modifiers

Comment: Does `@click.right` work with mouse right click?

Comment: no, it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to catch the [mouseDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event

```
<div id="root">
  <button @mouseDown.middle="test">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  methods: {
    test () {
        alert('me')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same bug as `@click.right` that isn't working in 2.2.1: [bug report](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5330).

It seems to be fixed in Vue 2.3+

PS can't test it, as my laptop hasn't a middle mouse button. Also double tab is a right click on my laptop ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

```
<div id="root">
  <button @click.middle.exact="test()">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  methods: {
    test () {
        alert('me')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).